# Excel VBA For Multiple SUMIFS on Large Data set

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently new on VBA and have been working on a Code which is applied on large data set on excel sheet. The goal is to create a material movement of various materials through that large data.
Therefore i used a sumifs approach to target specific cells which meets multiple Criteria.

So i created so so many arrays and applied if statements on them and looped them to get the results

But due to so many loops being happening, the excel sheets always get slowed down and crash.

So i am asking, if there is any alternative way to achieve the same results or should i improve my VBA code to make it more efficient.

I have attached file for your reference.

Thank You
Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
    Sub FinishSingle1()


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


    Dim MB5B As Worksheet
    Set MB5B = Worksheets("MB5B")
    
    Dim Mvt As Worksheet
    Set Mvt = Worksheets("Finish Movement")
    
    Dim MM As Worksheet
    Set MM = Worksheets("MM60")
    
    Dim Mb As Worksheet
    Set Mb = Worksheets("MB51")
        
        
    Mvt.Activate
      
        
 ' Creating Dynamic First And Last Row
 
 
 ' Creating First Row
 
    Dim MvFRow As Integer
    Dim QFRow As Integer
    
    MvFRow = Mvt.Cells.Find("Material Code").Row + 1
    QFRow = Worksheets("MB51").Cells.Find("Material").Row + 1
  
    
 'Creating Last Row
     
     
    Dim TRow As Long
    TRow = MB5B.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim MMRow As Long
    MMRow = MM.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim MBRow As Long
    MBRow = Mb.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim MvtRow As Long
    MvtRow = Mvt.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    
  ' Apply Profit Centre
    
    
    Dim III As Integer
    
    For III = 2 To TRow
    
    
    If Range("C" & III + 4).Value = 1002 Then
    Range("D" & III + 4).Value = 1011
    
    ElseIf Range("C" & III + 4).Value = 1003 Then
    Range("D" & III + 4).Value = 1021
    
    ElseIf Range("C" & III + 4).Value = 1004 Then
    Range("D" & III + 4).Value = 1022
    
    ElseIf Range("C" & III + 4).Value = 1005 Then
    Range("D" & III + 4).Value = 1041
    
    ElseIf Range("C" & III + 4).Value = 1006 Then
    Range("D" & III + 4).Value = 1032
    
    End If
     
     
    Next III
     



     Dim PrQ1() As Range, PrQ2() As Range, PrQ3() As Range, PrQ4() As Range, PrQ5() As Range, PrQ6() As 
     Range
   
    Dim MvtQ1() As Range, MvtQ2() As Range, MvtQ3() As Range, MvtQ4() As Range, MvtQ5() As Range, MvtQ6() 
    As Range, _
    MvtQ7() As Range, MvtQ8() As Range, MvtQ9() As Range, MvtQ10() As Range, MvtQ11() As Range, MvtQ12() 
    As Range, _
    MvtQ13() As Range, MvtQ14() As Range, MvtQ15() As Range, MvtQ16() As Range, MvtQ17() As Range, 
    MvtQ18() As Range, _
    MvtQ19() As Range, MvtQ20() As Range, MvtQ21() As Range, MvtQ22() As Range, MvtQ23() As Range, 
    MvtQ24() As Range, _
    MvtQ25() As Range, MvtQ26() As Range, MvtQ27() As Range, MvtQ28() As Range, MvtQ29() As Range, 
    MvtQ30() As Range, _
    MvtQ31() As Range, MvtQ32() As Range, MvtQ33() As Range, MvtQ34() As Range, MvtQ35() As Range, 
    MvtQ36() As Range, _
    MvtQ37() As Range, MvtQ38() As Range, MvtQ39() As Range, MvtQ40() As Range, MvtQ41() As Range, 
    MvtQ42() As Range, _
    MvtQ43() As Range, MvtQ44() As Range, MvtQ45() As Range, MvtQ46() As Range
   
   
    ReDim PrQ1(QFRow To MBRow) As Range, PrQ2(QFRow To MBRow) As Range, PrQ3(QFRow To MBRow) As Range, _
    PrQ4(QFRow To MBRow) As Range, PrQ5(QFRow To MBRow) As Range, PrQ6(QFRow To MBRow) As Range
   
    ReDim MvtQ1(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ2(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ3(MvFRow To MvtRow) As 
    Range, _
    MvtQ4(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ5(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ6(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, 
    _
    MvtQ7(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ8(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ9(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, 
    _
    MvtQ10(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ11(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ12(MvFRow To MvtRow) As 
    Range, _
    MvtQ13(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ14(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ15(MvFRow To MvtRow) As 
    Range, _
    MvtQ16(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ17(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ18(MvFRow To MvtRow) As 
    Range, _
    MvtQ19(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ20(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ21(MvFRow To MvtRow) As 
    Range, _
    MvtQ22(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ23(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ24(MvFRow To MvtRow) As 
    Range, _
    MvtQ25(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ26(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ27(MvFRow To MvtRow) As 
    Range, _
    MvtQ28(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ29(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ30(MvFRow To MvtRow) As 
    Range, _
    MvtQ31(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ32(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ33(MvFRow To MvtRow) As 
    Range, _
    MvtQ34(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ35(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ36(MvFRow To MvtRow) As 
    Range, _
    MvtQ37(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ38(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ39(MvFRow To MvtRow) As 
    Range, _
    MvtQ40(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ41(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ42(MvFRow To MvtRow) As 
    Range, _
    MvtQ43(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ44(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range, MvtQ45(MvFRow To MvtRow) As 
    Range, _
    MvtQ46(MvFRow To MvtRow) As Range
   

' Dynamic Columns For Looping

' Movement Column Numbers

    Dim Mv1co As Integer, Mv2co As Integer, Mv3co As Integer, Mv4co As Integer, Mv5co As Integer, Mv6co 
    As Integer, _
    Mv7co As Integer, Mv8co As Integer, Mv9co As Integer, Mv10co As Integer, Mv11co As Integer, Mv12co As 
    Integer, _
    Mv13co As Integer, Mv14co As Integer, Mv15co As Integer, Mv16co As Integer, Mv17co As Integer, Mv18co 
    As Integer, _
    Mv19co As Integer, Mv20co As Integer, Mv21co As Integer, Mv22co As Integer, Mv23co As Integer, Mv24co 
    As Integer, _
    Mv25co As Integer, Mv26co As Integer, Mv27co As Integer, Mv28co As Integer, Mv29co As Integer, Mv30co 
    As Integer, _
    Mv31co As Integer, Mv32co As Integer, Mv33co As Integer, Mv34co As Integer, Mv35co As Integer, Mv36co 
    As Integer, _
    Mv37co As Integer, Mv38co As Integer, Mv39co As Integer, Mv40co As Integer, Mv41co As Integer, Mv42co 
    As Integer, _
    Mv43co As Integer, Mv44co As Integer, Mv45co As Integer, Mv46co As Integer
    
    

    Mv1co = Mvt.Cells.Find("Material Code", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    Mv2co = Mvt.Cells.Find("Opening Qty").Column
    Mv3co = Mvt.Cells.Find("Opening Value").Column
    Mv4co = Mvt.Cells.Find("Purchase / Production Qty").Column
    Mv5co = Mvt.Cells.Find("Purchase / Production Value").Column
    Mv9co = Mvt.Cells.Find("T.P Special Stock Qty").Column
    Mv10co = Mvt.Cells.Find("T.P Special Stock Amount").Column
    Mv13co = Mvt.Cells.Find("S.T Receipt Qty").Column
    Mv14co = Mvt.Cells.Find("S.T Receipt Value").Column
    Mv16co = Mvt.Cells.Find("M. M Transfer Qty").Column
    Mv17co = Mvt.Cells.Find("M. M Transfer Value").Column
    Mv19co = Mvt.Cells.Find("Consumption Qty").Column
    Mv20co = Mvt.Cells.Find("Consumption Value").Column
    Mv25co = Mvt.Cells.Find("T.P Special Stock Qty").Column
    Mv26co = Mvt.Cells.Find("T.P Special Stock Amount").Column
    Mv29co = Mvt.Cells.Find("Cost Centre Qty").Column
    Mv30co = Mvt.Cells.Find("Cost Centre Value").Column
    Mv32co = Mvt.Cells.Find("S.T Consume Qty").Column
    Mv33co = Mvt.Cells.Find("S.T Consume Value").Column
    Mv35co = Mvt.Cells.Find("M.Transfer Posting Qty").Column
    Mv36co = Mvt.Cells.Find("M.Transfer Posting Value").Column
    Mv37co = Mvt.Cells.Find("Material to Material Transfer Qty").Column
    Mv38co = Mvt.Cells.Find("Material to Material Transfer Value").Column
    Mv40co = Mvt.Cells.Find("C.S Qty As Per Movement").Column
    Mv41co = Mvt.Cells.Find("C.S Value As Per Movement").Column
    Mv42co = Mvt.Cells.Find("C.S Qty As Per MB5B").Column
    Mv43co = Mvt.Cells.Find("C.S Value As Per MB5B").Column
    Mv44co = Mvt.Cells.Find("Difference Qty").Column
    Mv45co = Mvt.Cells.Find("Difference Values").Column
    Mv46co = Mvt.Cells.Find("Plant Name").Column
    

' MB51 Columns Numbers

    Dim MCo1 As Integer, MCo2 As Integer, MCo3 As Integer, MCo4 As Integer, MCo5 As Integer, MCo6 As 
    Integer
    
    MCo1 = Mb.Cells.Find("Material", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    MCo2 = Mb.Cells.Find("Movement type").Column
    MCo3 = Mb.Cells.Find("Quantity", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    MCo4 = Mb.Cells.Find("Amt.in loc.cur.").Column
    MCo5 = Mb.Cells.Find("Movement Type Text").Column
    MCo6 = Mb.Cells.Find("Plant").Column
   
'  Looping Starts From Here
      
   
    Dim I As Long
    Dim II As Long
   
    For I = LBound(MvtQ1) To UBound(MvtQ1)
    
    Set MvtQ1(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv1co)
    Set MvtQ4(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv4co)
    Set MvtQ5(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv5co)
    Set MvtQ9(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv9co)
    Set MvtQ10(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv10co)
    Set MvtQ13(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv13co)
    Set MvtQ14(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv14co)
    Set MvtQ16(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv16co)
    Set MvtQ17(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv17co)
    Set MvtQ19(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv19co)
    Set MvtQ20(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv20co)
    Set MvtQ25(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv25co)
    Set MvtQ26(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv26co)
    Set MvtQ29(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv29co)
    Set MvtQ30(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv30co)
    Set MvtQ32(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv32co)
    Set MvtQ33(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv33co)
    Set MvtQ35(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv35co)
    Set MvtQ36(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv36co)
    Set MvtQ37(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv37co)
    Set MvtQ38(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv38co)
    Set MvtQ40(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv40co)
    Set MvtQ41(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv41co)
    Set MvtQ42(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv42co)
    Set MvtQ43(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv43co)
    Set MvtQ44(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv44co)
    Set MvtQ45(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv45co)
    Set MvtQ46(I) = Mvt.Cells(I, Mv46co)
   
   
   
    For II = LBound(PrQ1) To UBound(PrQ1)
    
    Set PrQ1(II) = Mb.Cells(II, MCo1)
    Set PrQ2(II) = Mb.Cells(II, MCo2)
    Set PrQ3(II) = Mb.Cells(II, MCo3)
    Set PrQ4(II) = Mb.Cells(II, MCo4)
    Set PrQ5(II) = Mb.Cells(II, MCo5)
    Set PrQ6(II) = Mb.Cells(II, MCo6)
   
   
    If MvtQ1(I).Value = PrQ1(II).Value And MvtQ46(I).Value = PrQ6(II).Value Then
    
      
    If PrQ2(II).Value = "101" And PrQ5(II).Value = "GR for order" Then
        MvtQ4(I).Value = MvtQ4(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ5(I).Value = MvtQ5(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
        
    ElseIf PrQ2(II).Value = "102" And PrQ5(II).Value = "GR for order    rev." Then
        MvtQ4(I).Value = MvtQ4(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ5(I).Value = MvtQ5(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
        
    ElseIf PrQ2(II).Value = "101" And PrQ5(II).Value = "GR for sales ord.st." Then
        MvtQ4(I).Value = MvtQ4(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ5(I).Value = MvtQ5(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
        
    End If
    
    
    
    If PrQ2(II).Value = "68E" And PrQ3(II).Value > 0 Then
        MvtQ9(I).Value = MvtQ9(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ10(I).Value = MvtQ10(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
    
    ElseIf PrQ2(II).Value = "68A" And PrQ3(II).Value > 0 Then
        MvtQ9(I).Value = MvtQ9(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ10(I).Value = MvtQ10(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
    
    ElseIf PrQ2(II).Value = "68B" And PrQ3(II).Value > 0 Then
        MvtQ9(I).Value = MvtQ9(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ10(I).Value = MvtQ10(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value

    End If
    
    
    
    If PrQ2(II).Value = "351" And PrQ4(II).Value > 0 Then
        MvtQ13(I).Value = MvtQ13(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ14(I).Value = MvtQ14(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
        
    ElseIf PrQ2(II).Value = "309" And PrQ4(II).Value > 0 Then
        MvtQ13(I).Value = MvtQ13(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ14(I).Value = MvtQ14(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
    
    ElseIf PrQ2(II).Value = "310" And PrQ4(II).Value < 0 Then
        MvtQ13(I).Value = MvtQ13(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ14(I).Value = MvtQ14(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
        
    End If
    
    
    
    If PrQ2(II).Value = "601" Then
        MvtQ19(I).Value = MvtQ19(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ20(I).Value = MvtQ20(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
        
    ElseIf PrQ2(II).Value = "602" Then
        MvtQ19(I).Value = MvtQ19(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ20(I).Value = MvtQ20(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
      
    ElseIf PrQ2(II).Value = "453" And PrQ4(II).Value <> 0 Then
        MvtQ19(I).Value = MvtQ19(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ20(I).Value = MvtQ20(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
        
    End If
    
    
    
    If PrQ2(II).Value = "68A" And PrQ3(II).Value < 0 Then
        MvtQ25(I).Value = MvtQ25(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ26(I).Value = MvtQ26(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
    
    ElseIf PrQ2(II).Value = "68B" And PrQ3(II).Value < 0 Then
        MvtQ25(I).Value = MvtQ25(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ26(I).Value = MvtQ26(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
    
    ElseIf PrQ2(II).Value = "68E" And PrQ3(II).Value < 0 Then
        MvtQ25(I).Value = MvtQ25(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ26(I).Value = MvtQ26(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
    
    End If
    
    
    
    If PrQ2(II).Value = "331" And PrQ4(II).Value < 0 Then
        MvtQ29(I).Value = MvtQ29(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ30(I).Value = MvtQ30(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
            
    ElseIf PrQ2(II).Value = "Z61" And PrQ4(II).Value < 0 Then
        MvtQ29(I).Value = MvtQ29(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ30(I).Value = MvtQ30(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
            
    End If
    
    
    
    If PrQ2(II).Value = "351" And PrQ4(II).Value < 0 Then
        MvtQ32(I).Value = MvtQ32(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ33(I).Value = MvtQ33(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
            
    End If
    
    
    
    If PrQ2(II).Value = "321" And PrQ4(II).Value < 0 Then
        MvtQ35(I).Value = MvtQ35(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ36(I).Value = MvtQ36(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
            
    End If
    
    
    
    If PrQ2(II).Value = "309" And PrQ3(II).Value < 0 And PrQ4(II).Value < 0 Then
        MvtQ37(I).Value = MvtQ37(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ38(I).Value = MvtQ38(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
        
    ElseIf PrQ2(II).Value = "310" And PrQ3(II).Value > 0 And PrQ4(II).Value > 0 Then
        MvtQ37(I).Value = MvtQ37(I).Value + PrQ3(II).Value
        MvtQ38(I).Value = MvtQ38(I).Value + PrQ4(II).Value
                    
    End If
        
        
        
    End If
    

    Next II
    Next I
    
    
' Call FinishSingle2
    
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 

     
    End Sub
```

[Below is a Link to Sample File]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N1UABSto0xlNyeMja-WqYUjEJ6rTzv95/view?usp=sharing

Please Note That I have made 5 different Inventory Movement modules, But i have only shared Finished Inventory module VBA code here which targets MB51 and MB5B sheets which are available in the file. All of others Inventory modules follow same pattern. And majority of arrays that i have defined are ranges and column names which i needed for sumifs multiple criteria.

You can find above code under module named as FinishMvtSingle

All of these VBA run from Dashboard sheet from their respective sections and the sample data relates to Plant 1003 which is already selected in the finish movement section.

Thank You

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. That's a fare chuck of load on the memory (which I suspect is why it's crashing). Can you provide a sample of your sheet and sample of your end result?

Comment: I found it very difficult to follow your code and understand what it is exactly you want to achieve. As you said, you are using so so many (far too many) arrays. This is most likely the problem, because sooner or later you're likely to run out of memory. You are also using far too many line continuations unnecessarily when declaring these arrays. Anyway, as @Zac suggested can you provide a sample of your file?

Comment: Thank you for your kind responses, yes i agree that due to the large block of code it may affecting the memory and resulting in the crash. Okay i will share my end result with you guys. but i cannot seem to find the attachment option here. lol

Comment: Dear Zac and super Symmetry, I have included the link to sample file for your understanding of end result.
Password is: Imp437044

Comment: @Zac Please look into this now

Comment: @SuperSymmetry I have provide some more clarifications for this code in the last line.

Comment: I've had a quick look at your sheet (although I didn't download it).. I think what you are asking for will take some time to resolve in the format you have it in at the moment. I would suggest: break down your query. Start with first step and ask how can you improve on it. Otherwise, the way it stands, it will just take too long to go through the whole thing